# Can't find any info/documentation on Ros Node: /ros_camera_preview_view

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an app that sends images to Ros through networking, and when I connect it "/ros_camera_preview_view" appears when I use "rosnode list" I've searching the web but I can't find any documentation for this /ros_camera_preview_view node? How would I retrieve images in this node in C++ code? And what packages should I include because when I try to include "ros_camera_preview_view" Ros will tell me that the package doesn't exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312772/can%27t-find-any-info/documentation-on-ros-node:-/ros_camera_preview_view/) by [ROStutorialLearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/39462/rostutoriallearner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have an app [..], and when I connect it "/ros_camera_preview_view" appears when I use "rosnode list" I've searching the web but I can't find any documentation for this /ros_camera_preview_view node?

`/ros_camera_preview_view` is the *name*, not a node *type*, so unless the name is exactly identical to the type, chances are you won't find anything when searching for the name.

> I have an app [..]

Since you mention "app", I assume you're running this on a phone. I'd try to get some more info from whoever / wherever you got the app.

If that is not possible, try doing a `rosnode info /ros_camera_preview_view` and see what the ROS API is that the node exposes (ie: topics, services, actions, etc).

Then for each of the topics listed, do a `rostopic info <topic_name>` and a `rostopic type <topic_name>` (there should be tab-completion). That should help you figure out the types that are being used. Do the same for any services, but use `rosservice info <service_name>` and `rosservice type <service_name>`.

> How would I retrieve images in this node in C++ code?

Seeing as you mention "sends images to Ros", I'm going to guess it has at least one topic onto which [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html)s are being published (or any of the compressed versions). In that case, you'll want to check [Writing a Simple Image Subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/SubscribingToImages) (Python version [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/WritingImagePublisherSubscriber)).

> when I try to include "ros_camera_preview_view" Ros will tell me that the package doesn't exist?

That's not how this works, but that will probably become clear from the tutorial(s) I linked.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROStutorialLearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/39462/rostutoriallearner/) on 2019-01-16**:
Thanks for your answer it's helped me a lot and after following the tutorial I end up with the following error when trying to apply it to my code; See the update in the OP.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-16**:\

> I end up with the following error when trying to apply it to my code; See the update in the OP.

please do not post follow-up questions in the same question. ROS Answers is not a regular forum: it works best with a 1-to-1 ratio of questions and answers.

If your initial question was answered, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-16**:
.. please mark it as such by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of the answer that answered it.

If you then have additional questions, post a new question, clearly stating in the text that it is a follow-up to one of your previous questions.

I would also recommend to undo your edit.